# UITableVIew rows visible only when scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView which I'm populating with an array. Initially only the first row is visible and when it is pull up the rows below appear one by one.

And when I pull down back to top the rows at the bottom start to disappear one by one. I don't  understand what's going on.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here's the cellForRowAtIndexPath code

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell *cell;
        if(tabIndex==2){
            if([dataDictionary valueForKey:@"myFriends"]){
                cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCircle" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                NSArray *array = [dataDictionary valueForKey:@"myFriends"];
                UIImageView *profileImage = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
                CALayer *imageLayer = profileImage.layer;
                [imageLayer setCornerRadius:25];
                [imageLayer setBorderWidth:0.6];
                [imageLayer setBorderColor:[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor];
                [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
                UILabel *uname = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
                UILabel *description = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
                [profileImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
                uname.text = [[array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"name"];
                description.text = [[array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"description"];
            }else
                cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EmptyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        if(tabIndex==3){

        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: I'm out now. I will share it shortly. However the code is usual

Comment: What is the array count you are using? is Same as what you have given in the numberofrowsinsection ?

Comment: yeah same, if it was different there would have been a crash

Comment: need to see your 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' code.

Comment: @JayGajjar Please see the code

Comment: there is some mistake in your logic EmptyCell are loaded first and when you scrolldown myCircle cell is loaded. Put a breakpoint and check the flow

Comment: no its going straight in the correct cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, after a detailed inspection the error was finally caught.

[image]

If you see in image 1st the Autoresizing is applied for stretching and positioning which doesn't seem to reflect on the view at left but at runtime it does shows erratic behavior. Changed that in the 2nd image and everything ran fine.

[image]

You may also try `clipSubviews`.